# Python ImportError: No module named system

Tags: system

```
import system module does not work in python2.7.3
```

Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55)

```
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

 >>> import system
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named system
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish for the sys module, try:

```
import sys
```

If you're looking for the system call, try:

```
import os.system
```